# Why is my site rendering over and over again?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, bootstrap-4

Been up to speed with with a udemy course on react and redux on building a simple video player until my site started rendering the same page over 10 times as though in a loop as shown below. Kindly help we troubleshoot this.
Attached are my project files for the various components.
[see picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iagUV.png)

This file contains the app(parent) component.

```js
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import SearchBar from './components/search_bar';
import YTSearch from 'youtube-api-search';
import VideoList from './components/video_list';
import VideoDetail from './components/video_detail';

const API_KEY = 'AIzaSyCAfItybV7pSzxmwTj5wyG5SErMs5HYlRQ';

class App extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {videos: []};

    YTSearch({key: API_KEY, term: 'internet of things'}, (videos) => {
      this.setState({videos});
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SearchBar />
        <VideoDetail video={this.state.videos[0]} />
        <VideoList videos={this.state.videos} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.container'));
```

video_detail.js file has code for the VideoDetail component

```js
import React from 'react';

const VideoDetail = ({video}) =>{
  if (!video){
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  const videoId = video.id.videoId;
  const url = `www.youtube.com/embed/${videoId}`;

  return(
    <div className="video-detail col-md-8">
      <div className="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
        <iframe className="embed-responsive-item" src = {url}></iframe>
      </div>
      <div className="details">
      <div>{video.snippet.title}</div>
      <div>{video.snippet.description}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default VideoDetail;
```

video_list_item.js contains code for the VideoListItem component

```js
import React from 'react';

const VideoListItem = ({video}) =>{

const imgUrl = video.snippet.thumbnails.default.url;

  return(
    <li className = "list-group-item">
      <div className ="video-list media" >
        <div className ="media-left">
          <img className = "media-object" src = {imgUrl}/>
        </div>

        <div className = "media-body">
          <div className = "media-heading">{video.snippet.title}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  )
}

export default VideoListItem;
```

video_list.js contains code for the VideoList component as shown below

```js
import React from 'react';
import VideoListItem from './video_list_item';

const VideoList = (props) => {
  const videoItems = props.videos.map((video) => {
    return <VideoListItem video = {video} key = {video.etag} />;
  });
  return(
    <ul className="col-md-4 list-group">
      {videoItems}
    </ul>
  );
}

export default VideoList;
```

search_bar.js contains code for the SearchBar component i have not yet wired though.

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class SearchBar extends Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {term: ''};
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <input />
      </div>
    );
  }
};

export default SearchBar;
```

index.html contains code for the page to load component and a link to boostrap

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAq06l5RUVfib62IYRQacLc-KAy0XIWAVs"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container"></div>
  </body>
  <script src="/bundle.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: This is a very very rough guess as I can't actually try the problem (It's worth including a working example if you can) but the image looks like you're recursively including the same page in the iframe. Again, massive guesswork, but you may need to add `http://` on the front of your URL `const url = www.youtube.com/embed/${videoId};` for it to be correctly linked to.

Comment: If you can, provide github link for your project. Or even better you can clone your project on stackblitz (which is a great tool) and provide link of working example.

Comment: does your app have multiple HTML elements with  className as `container`

Comment: @DBS This happened to solve the issue. Thanks for the guess

Comment: @Revansiddh Not at all, editing the url variable in the VideoDetail component happened to solve the issue. Thanks for the try

Comment: @AkshayMilmile https://github.com/ahebwa49/react-video-player.git 
However, editing the url variable in the VideoDetail component to include https:// happened to solve the issue. Thanks for the try.